# British quotation rules

Tags: punctuation, quotes

If the full stop doesn't belong to the quotation, which punctuation option is preferred in British English?

1. He said, 'I've finished.'
2. He said, 'I've finished'.

Comment: Hello, linozaze. I don't see how 'the full stop doesn't belong to the quotation (or rather, defining more rigorously, the actual spoken words – 'quotation' can apply to words in texts, on placards etc)' with your example. Here, a full stop is rarely commanded in direct speech (ie someone actually iterating the words "Full stop!") but often implied. Here, _I've finished_ is a complete/d sentence, so the full stop belongs with it (in many people's chosen styles). // I don't subscribe to the conception that there exists a definitive 'British English'.

Comment: The quotation is concluded with the period (you've provided no context that indicates it isn't), so it goes inside the final quotation mark.